# Showing data into Label OnTextChanged event of TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

let say I enter a code into textbox 100 but into label Pizza should be texted in label

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void txtMain_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
   lblmain.text = txtcat.text;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are so many things wrong in your question. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: So what is the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The `OnTextChanged` is a server side event . It would be better to use JavaScript for this purpose like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change() {
        document.getElementById('<%= lblmain.ClientID %>').innerHTML = document.getElementById('<%= txtMain.ClientID %>').value;
    }
</script>
```

And then in your `TextBox` call to `change` function like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMain" runat="server" onkeydown="change();"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="lblmain" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```