# Search ImageButton in Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a `TextBox`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textSearch" runat="server" Width="80" ForeColor="Black" />
```

and a `Repeater` with `ImageButtons`:

```
<asp:Panel ID="panRepeater" runat="server" ScrollBars="Vertical">
     <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater" runat="server">
         <ItemTemplate> 
             <asp:ImageButton ID="imgSearchResult" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>'/> 
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:Repeater>
 </asp:Panel>
```

In code behind, I add the Images to the `ImageButtons` with this function:

```
private void LoadImages()
{
        string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images/ORAS"));
        List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image> images = new List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image>(filesindirectory.Count());

        foreach (string item in filesindirectory)
        {
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image image = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
            image.ImageUrl = (String.Format("~/Images/ORAS/{0}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item)));
            images.Add(image);
        }

        Repeater.DataSource = images;
        Repeater.DataBind();
}
```

I want to be able to search and only display the wanted `ImageButtons` similar to this example:

[image: Search Example]

I would type in `00` into the `Search-TextBox` and all `ImageButtons`, which contain `00` will be shown. The thing is that I'd have to do this after every `KeyDown`.

Comment: I don't think you can do this be server side events. The `TextBox` is a server control and `OnTextChanged` is a server side event. It would be better to use JavaScript for this purpose.

Comment: @user2946329 I see. What is the best approach for doing this in JavaScript?

Comment: Here is a very simple example of how using JavaScript to get the `TextBox`'s `Text` on `onkeydown` event of `TextBox`. Then you can do more logic to filter your `Repeater` based on given `TextBox`'s value. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34434842/2946329

Comment: @user2946329 Thank you. I'll have a look at it :)

Comment: Also consider using Ajax and `UpdatePanel` maybe good for these purposes.

Comment: @user2946329 I'm not really a fan of Ajax, but I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 2):

This is a complex scenario and can be implemented in two different ways.

1. Using ajax postback by hooking up a server-side text changed event of search textbox. In this server-side event, you would get records from database using the search text box text value. An example of a similar scenario using gridview can be found at this URL: [Server-side Search](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/search-into-textbox-and-bind-gridview-using-asp-net1)
2. The second approach, which is more prefered is calling the server-side method to get records directly from JavaScript or jquery. This can be very quick and fast. An example of such a scenario using gridview can be found at this URL: [Search using client-side code](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Search-and-Filter-GridView-as-you-type-in-TextBox-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx).

For the second option, you have to hookup client-side `keyup` event to get search text before making an ajax call to a web service method from jquery, and also only do a search if user has input a minimum number of characters like 2 or 3 or 4 or whatever you think is a good number. The web service method on server-side will return a JSON collection of the searched items for your repeater control. *Finally*,  in the success event of jquery ajax call you would need to populate the repeater items with the search items.

**A Suggestion**

Also, as another suggestion to make it easier to implement the client-side solution  you could create an html string in the web service method and then in success event of jquery ajax call just set the innerHTML of a div to this html, so in jquery just one line of code in success event would populate the repeater control. This would be easier than returning a JSON collection from web service and then in success event of jquery ajax call you would need to create/populate html into the repeater control using DOM manipulation which would need some jquery.

Comment: Uuah, that sounds complicated. I guess I have no choice but to learn JS/jquery. Thank you for you help.

Comment: This is not simple. Its like doing a full project. Look at the demo and code in second approach, its pretty easy once you follow how jquery is used to populate the items. A demo can be seen at this URL: http://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/685/.

Comment: Also, I would first try to follow the easier option, which is the first  approach since its all server-side and therefore easier to implement.

Comment: That might be problematic due to time restrictions. Nonetheless, thank you for your advice. I'll see if I can create something usable.

Comment: In  that case, I would recommend to just dive into the second approach.   If you have questions feel free to ask me here.

Comment: I'll take you up on that offer. Thank you very much.

Comment: You should view this ASP.Net demo based on DataList control: http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/samples/ctrlref/data/DataList/DataList5_vb.aspx. The full source code can be obtained from this URL: http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/datalist.aspx by clicking `View Source` button.