# TextChanged event not triggered on Safari

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got the following code in an .aspx.cs file:

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.Redirect(

            HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString() + "&parameter1=" + TextBox1.Text.ToString()

            );
    }
```

This is obviously triggered by entering something in a textbox in ascx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" name="tb1" runat="server" value="" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

I should be redirected as expected to the current url, to which "&parameter1=" is appended, followed by the value entered in the textbox. On Safari this doesn't work, what is the explanation for this and do you know of any workarounds? (it works on other browsers)

Comment: have you seen the logs is there anything preventing the event call ??

Comment: The `OnTextChanged` is a server side event . It would be better to use JavaScript for this purpose. Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34434592/showing-data-into-label-ontextchanged-event-of-textbox

Comment: You need to call the _postback() function for your textbox control when the onkeyup is raised using javascript.

Comment: Add `AutoPostBack="true"` to the textbox